# Function to time the recalculation time of workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for an inbuilt function or maybe a VBA segment that will give me the re calculation time for a spreadsheet to complete the calculation

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site isn't really for broad "how do I..." questions; it's for specific programming questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option explicit
Function CalculationTime() as date
Dim Start as date
Start = now
Application.calculate
Do until application.calculationstate = xldone
Doevents
Loop
CalculationTime = now - Start
End function
```

Untested and written on mobile, sorry for bad formatting. Returns a date (time duration), but you could format(CalculationTime,"mm:ss") to return as string, or change function to return as double, then multiply by 24*60*60 to get seconds. If you wanted more accuracy, you could use ticker/Timer function.